# Comparing game-state over network?

Tags: c#

I'm making a turn-based multiplayer game in c# and would like to have a simple check to see if the state is in sync after each move/command/turn. The state is too big to send every time, so I was looking into something like a hash.

If I understand it correctly, however, in C# the default `GetHashCode` for classes is based on the object's pointer, so this wouldn't work to check the equality over a network.

Now my question: Should I just override `GetHashCode` for all my state classes, or is there a better/easier way?

The game is still in very early development, and the state is constantly changing, so it would be quite annoying that every time I add or change something in my state I would also have to update the `GetHashCode` method. That's why I haven't actually tried overriding it yet, hoping there is a simpler way.

Note: I'm working in Unity, so it's c# version 3 apparently.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you have no other way than generate your own check routine. Even a hash is not a good idea as there can be different values resulting on the same hash.

Comment: C# *2*?  Are you sure?  Please double-check which version of C# you're using.  C# 2 is pretty old now (2006).

Comment: Unity still uses a modified version of Mono 2.6, which is .net 2.0 I believer. They're working on upgrading it, hopefully not too much longer.

Comment: You're correct.  Hash values are **not portable** across systems.

Comment: @Gusman Not yet I think. For now they're still on .net 2.0. They're working on it though. I might be mistaken however, could you give a link to where you got this information?

Comment: It's not C#5, it's C# 3, it uses FW 3.5: http://www.unityninjas.com/new-technology/c-6-in-unity/ My bad :D

Comment: @Gusman You seem to be right, version 3 it is :P Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on a turn based game, then a block chain approach may be of interest to you.
It may allow you to detect tampering client side.

Eg:

Turn 1 : Player 1 -> Player 2 : Attack  : This information is hashed (Sha256?)

Turn 2 : Player 2 -> Player 1 : Taunt + Previous Hash : This information is hashed (Sha256)

Turn 3: Repeat on and on and on..

Using this approach, you query the hash information from the clients, and determine who, if anyone, has a different hash.
The person with the different hash is most likely the one who has tampered with their turn data.

The only caveat to this is that you would need to include some sort of header information in the data to determine what turn everyone is on. 
Eg: you don't want to label player 1 as someone who has tampered with the data, just because they have turn information that player 2 hasn't received yet. 
That being the case: you could attach the turn number or index to the transmission as the hashes are sent across the network. So if Player 2 receives a hash for a turn he hasn't got yet, then he will respect it and save it.
If he however gets a hash for a turn he already has - he should probably check with the other players to see what hash they have for the same turn.

Note : this provides you with a means of verifying the entire history of turns in a game, as well as checking to see if everyone is in sync.

Its inspired by Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

Have whoever is hosting have a sequence and generate a number whenever a move is made. Sync by getting current sequence and make sure the client has the same number, if not, get all of the moves up to that point that have the ID of that sequence.

Comment: Could you give an example, I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: You have to keep records of every move. I don't know what kind of game it is, but maybe you need to store an X and Y coordinate. So those moves have to be stored with an ID that you can get by generating a new sequence. Have a method that gets the last move ID and if the client isn't up to date, get the last moves.